# Play-By-Post - On Races and joining

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, races, play-by-post

I’m pretty new to PbP so please bear with me if I screw up in what I wish to ask. I am wondering if someone could help/advise me on a few questions I have.

Though I am relatively experienced at PbP and have the time to devote to it, I am having problems Finding a good Dungeons & Dragons / Sword & sorcery type game that will let me join. Maybe its just me?

Three problems I am finding - Everyplace!

1. Every play by post I’ve encountered so far is just hack, slash and see who lives. No real Rollplaying or plot along the way. Are their any such critters out there still?
2. Of the few games I have found… When I asked about joining the answer was always the same. “The game is going on now and we have to many players as it is. Try back in six months or so maybe.” - Nice.
3. (This might be my problem) When playing a PbP I like to either have a more exotic race (Minotaur, Centaur fighter, mage etc) I Can play as a regular staple (Human, Elf, Dwarf, And so on, by the numbers) but I would prefer to have a bit more Roll play range. - I haven’t found Any games that will allow for more adventurous races 9or alternate gender, COME TO THINK ABOUT IT) Can’t quite figure out why but it seems a shame and limiting.

Anyway, can anyone suggest a place for me to go (Hmmm, maybe I should rephrase that…) - Could anyone suggest a place where I might find a game that has Rollplaying in addition to battles, that I can get in on this year and that might maybe accept a minotaur, centaur, slime or some other exotic type race? If so I’d be really grateful! I have plenty of time to devote to this hobby, if only I could find a place to have me. I’ve been out of touch awhile and what  Iam finding now is slim really.

I’ll admit I am asking this question in several PbP forums, so if ya see this post elsewhere…

Thnks for your time.

Crookshanks

Comment: This question is both too broad and not within the scope of RPG.Stackexchange. You will be better served waiting for a resonse on one of those other forums.

Comment: Hi there! This site is laser-focused on questions that can have objective answers, or “best” answers that can be backed up by experience. Your question is not a bad one, but it doesn't fit this site's laser focus. You will probably find sympathetic ears and useful advice on a discussion forum instead of a Stack. We have put together [a list of RPG discussion forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) that you might want to look over to help you choose a place to take this question. You might get more useful responses on a general forum rather than a PbP one, too. Cheers, and good luck!

Comment: Anyway, it's "role"-play. Roll-play (a wordplay on the similar sound of role and roll) is a degrading name for  that gaming style you don't want to get, the one where you just _roll_ dice and don't realy care about the _role_.